# У сервера гаснет физическая консоль, как это отключить?

Tags: linux, консоль, терминал

Я администрирую Linux-серверы (разных дистрибутивов - Ubuntu server, CentOS, Fedora) - физические и виртуальные машины. У большиснтва из них есть неприятная особенность - если в "физическую консоль" (которая не ssh, а в аппаратрном мониторе с аппаратной клавиатурой, реальной или удалённой через iKVM) длительное время ничего не "писать" с клавиатуры, она "гаснет".

В реальности это выглядит так: подходишь к серверу с физическим монитором, цепляешь его - монитор показывает чёрный экран. Цепляешь клавиатуру, нажимаешь any key - монитор оживает и становится видна "физическая консоль" (если речь идёт о машине без иксов - она видна всегда, начиная с загрузки ОС, если иксы есть - то её можно достичь через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). Или подключаешься к виртуальной машине по VNC - и то же самое, пока не тронешь клавиатуру - картинки нет.

Речь не идёт о "скринсейвере", это засыпание консоли происходит именно в текстовом режиме.

Как отучить Linux-хосты от такого поведения?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Описанное поведение исходит напрямую от ядра Linux, видимо это привет из далёкого прошлого, когда к таким хостам подключались текстовые терминалы с люминофорными устройствами визуализации, которые нужно было беречь от выгорания.

Проверить, через какое время физичекский терминал "погаснет" при отсутсвии пользовательского ввода в него, можно посмотрев на содержимое файла /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank:

```sh
$ cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank
600
```

Этот файл доступен только на чтение, изменить настройку, перезаписав его, нельзя. Значение в нём - это секунды, то есть в приведённом примере консоль "гаснет" через 10 минут простоя.

Чтобы отключить это поведение глобально и навсегда, следует добавить строку `consoleblank=0` к параметрам ядра в конфиге grub и перезагрузить ОС (не забыть про `update-grub` после редактирования). Например, так:

```sh
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep -v '#'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=7
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="consoleblank=0"
```

После перезагрузки видим, что параметры ядром считались и приняты:

```sh
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic root=UUID=544c13df-3ff3-47ba-94cc-407e414c6906 ro consoleblank=0
```

И настройка "засыпания" консоли изменилась:

```sh
$ cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank
0
```

Изменить этот параметр на лету, без перезагрузки, можно с помощью команды `setterm`, например так: `setterm -blank 0` или даже так: `setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 -powersave off`, однако тут есть целых два "НО":

1. это работает только, если команду `setterm` вводить в "физическую" консоль (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), а при вводе через ssh не работает
2. в Интернете пишут, что поведение `setterm` меняется от ядра к ядру и от дистрибутива к дистрибутиву, т.е. считать это способ вполне универсальным нельзя

Comment: Блин, чувак, ты очень кстати написал, я пол интернета перерыл, не знал как корректнее сформулировать вопрос, а тут вот прям вовремя. Спасибо большое.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/206622/turn-off-monitor-energy-saving-while-in-text-console-mode-in-linux - походу уже спрашивали и отвечали.