# Как настроить таймаут отключения монитора Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, экран

Для тестов мне понадобился linux server в качестве железа я использую старый *нетбук*, который в свою очередь закинул в дальний угол квартиры(для снижения шума). Но при закрытой крышки качество wifi падает, поэтому оставляю его открытым и он постоянно включен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно установить таймаут на отключение монитора ноутбука при бездействии(отсутствие нажатых клавиш), например 5 минут. Так-же подойдет вариант отключение монитора с помощью консоли(если такое возможно).

Ниже приведен скриншот с нужным параметром Ubuntu.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- установил Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Оно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563750/191416 ?